# moment.js - validate date > today and < 1 year from today

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to validate a date field on a test form.

The date must be greater than today, but no greater that 365 days form today.

I have tried many ways to get this code working, but I cannot see my error.

The code does not allow a user to enter a date that is between today and 1 year from today. A valid date gives the error message of: "Date must be greater than today."

I am unsure if the issue is my use of moment.js or my js code.

**Can anyone see the error I am making here?**

Here is my code:

```
var ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid = function(dateFormat, inputSelector) {
    var today = new moment();
    var todayPlusOneYear = new moment().add(365, 'days');
    var dateInput = $(inputSelector);
    var dateValue = dateInput.val();
    var dateMoment = null;

    if (dateValue.length > 0) {
        var dateMoment = moment(dateValue, dateFormat);
        if (dateMoment < today) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must be greater than today." %}';
            setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment < today, message);
        } else if (dateMoment > todayPlusOneYear) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must not be greater than 1 year from today." %}';
            setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment > todayPlusOneYear, message);
        }
    }
    return dateMoment;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use moment [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after) and [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) to compare moment objects instead of `<` and `>`.

In the [Query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) section of the docs there is a list of methods provided by moment to compare moment object. (e.g. `isBetween`, `isSameOrBefore`, `isSameOrAfter`, etc)

Your code could be like the following:

```
var ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid = function(dateFormat, inputSelector) {
    var today = new moment();
    var todayPlusOneYear = new moment().add(365, 'days');
    var dateInput = $(inputSelector);
    var dateValue = dateInput.val();
    var dateMoment = null;

    if (dateValue.length > 0) {
        var dateMoment = moment(dateValue, dateFormat);
        if (dateMoment.isBefore(today)) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must be greater than today." %}';
            setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment < today, message);
        } else if (dateMoment.isAfter(todayPlusOneYear)) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must not be greater than 1 year from today." %}';
            setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment > todayPlusOneYear, message);
        }
    }
    return dateMoment;
}
```

Here a live snippet with some test inputs:

```js
var ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid = function(dateFormat, dateValue) {
    var today = new moment();
    var todayPlusOneYear = new moment().add(365, 'days');
    //var dateInput = $(inputSelector);
    //var dateValue = dateInput.val();
    var dateMoment = null;

    if (dateValue.length > 0) {
        var dateMoment = moment(dateValue, dateFormat);
        if (dateMoment.isBefore(today)) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must be greater than today." %}';
            console.log(dateValue, message);
            //setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment < today, message);
        } else if (dateMoment.isAfter(todayPlusOneYear)) {
            var message = '{% trans "Date must not be greater than 1 year from today." %}';
            console.log(dateValue, message);
            //setParsleyErrorOnCondition(dateInput, dateMoment > todayPlusOneYear, message);
        } else {
            console.log(dateValue, "date ok");
        }
    }
    return dateMoment;
}

ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid('MM/YYYY', '05/2017');
ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid('MM/YYYY', '08/2017');
ensureLeadingEmploymentDateValid('MM/YYYY', '07/2018');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that inputs like `06/2017` parsed using `moment('06/2017', 'MM/YYYY')` will be interpreted as `2017-06-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Thanks VincenzoC, but I am still having the same issue. That is, a valid date is still not permitted. I cannot see the issue in the js else if condition.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input to reproduce the issue? Which is a valid date that is _not permitted_?

Comment: A valid date is `06/2017` to `06/2018` and an invalid date is `05/2017 & less` and `07/2018 and greater`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @user3354539 I've edited my answer adding a live snippet (simplified to show results for the given inputs) let me know where the code fails.

Comment: Thanks VincenzoC,